# JavaScript function that returns the VARIABLE NAME of a TYPE BOOLEAN instead of the VALUE itself inside Template Literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

is there a function in "javascript" where I can make my variables(not the value) as strings like parseVariableName something?

for example, in my scenario I want to have a **dynamic classname using boolean variables **without creating an object, making it as array and looping**. i want to return the variable name it self not the value of the variable. with that, i can use it inside template literals

```
const { isPivotable = true, isTable, isGrid } = props

const cn =  `myClass--sample ${isPivotable || isTable || isGrid}`

//or

const isPivotable = true, 
const isTable = false
const isGrid = false

const cn =  `myClass--sample ${isPivotable || isTable || isGrid}`

//value true is converted as STRING
actual result: *myClass--sample true* 

//the variable isPivotTable "name" converted as string
expected result: *myClass--sample isPivotable*
```

example of the expected result but uses objects, and arrays in which **I want to avoid**.

```
const parseVariableName = (obj) => Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val])=> !acc && val ? key : acc, '')

isPivotable = false
isGrid = false
isDraggableTable = true

const answer = `class-sample--${parseVariableName({ isPivotable, isGrid, isDraggableTable})}`
console.log(answer)
```

why i ask this question because i want to make a variable name base on the variable i declared and i don't want to make my code longer just because of it.

i know it's stupid question to ask but i just want to share my thoughts.

Comment: Not really. What I do: `const cns = ["myClass--sample"];` then `if (isPivotable || isTable || isGrid) cns.push("is-pivotable");`. When I render I use `cns.join(" ")`. You can also use `element.classList.add("is-pivotable");`

Comment: I also have a an answer to my problem but i'm looking a "javascript method"

here's my answer: `const variableNameToString = (obj) => Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val])=> !acc && val ? key : acc, '')

isPivotable = false
isGrid = false
isDraggableTable = true

const ans = `class-sample--${variableNameToString({ isPivotable, isGrid, isDraggableTable})}` `

Comment: *"is there a function in "javascript" where I can make my variables(not the value) as strings like parseVariableName something?"* No, there is not, and that seems to be a dangerous path anyway. The result would change if the code was processed by a minifier that renamed the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what exactly you are trying to achieve here. But to get your expected result, the following is what I can think of: You can put all your variables in an object instead of having it in the default `window` object. Here I am using `prop`. That way you can just pass the whole object inside a function where you check where the first `true` value occurs (which behaves almost like the OR chain in your example). And then return the `key` of the true value, which can be then used as a class. Below is a working example.

```js
let prop = {
    isPivotable: true,
    isTable: false,
    isGrid: false
}

function doCompare(prop) {
    let found = '';
    (Object.keys(prop)).some(x => {
        if (prop[x]) {
            found = x;
            return true;
        }
    })
    return found;
}

const cn = `myClass--sample ${doCompare(prop)}`

console.log(cn);
```

Comment: yeah I also got mine but using reduce. see at the comment section above.

Comment: I really doubt there is a more Javascript way of doing this. The variables we declare are nothing but properties of the `windows` object. It would be very difficult to run reduce on the large windows object.

Comment: i used reactjs.